# Is there any solution for Grails to select a folder like <input type="file"

Tags: file, grails, input, tags, directory

is there a solution to select a folderpath as comfortable like the input-file tag?

Answer (score 1):

Geeronimo- Not sure I fully understand your question, but I think the answer is "no", Grails is limited to the input/file capabilities of the standard HTML tag.

Comment: Yep, you'd need something like Flash, Silverlight, or an Applet to provide that type or rich interface.